# HighChart object expected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I am using highcharts to plot bar graphs. For enabling scroll bars i used Highstock.js. when highstock.js is added , throws exception as object expected in IE. Below is the code sample,

```
<script src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jsMethods.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

 <script src="../js/highstock.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>



 $(function () {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ 
  chart: {
  renderTo: 'CompareModal',
  type: 'column'
   },
     title: {
              text: '',
            },
     xAxis: {
              categories: color,
              min: 6
             },

      plotOptions: {

                  column: {
                            pointPadding: 0.2,
                            borderWidth: 0
                           }
                          },
                                scrollbar: {
                                    enabled: true
                                },

                                series: [{
                                    name: 'Volume',
                                    data: colorVolume

                                }]

                            });
                        })
```

Comment: where have you defined 'CompareModal' div?

Comment: <div id="CompareModal" class="col-md-12 col-md-12 table-responsive table-responsive_order_list"></div>  Inside the body tag

Comment: it's id should be 'CompareModal', as you're telling highcharts to render this chart to a div with 'CompareModal' id

Comment: id is CompareModal , pasted a wrong div

Comment: what's the value of colorVolume which you're assigning to data.. log it to console and check

Comment: I've recreated chart with your code giving dummy values.. one issue was min: 6 in xAxis, remove that.. if it still don't render then your values of color, colorVolume must be in wrong format.. one should be an array of strings and other, the array of numbers like i gave here: http://jsfiddle.net/u80x9pfr/

Comment: Like @AbdulJabbar said looks like colorVolume is not defined (if is... please try not to use global variables)

Comment: You cannot link highcharts/highstock at the same time. The highstock contains all highcharts features, so link only this one.

Comment: yes, that was the issue. refering only to highstock.js solved issue.